# Cannot find package eve-ng-addons-netem

Tags: 18.04, apt

I tried searching for the package **eve-ng-addons-netem** but received the following error:

```
E: Unable to locate package eve-ng-addons-netem
```

I checked on the Ubuntu [package directory](https://packages.ubuntu.com/) but could not find it. I have the base eve-ng installed and their [official site](https://www.eve-ng.net/index.php/documentation/howtos/howto-add-linux-netem/) does mention the package to install it.

Please note that I'm using a Ubuntu desktop version, and not server. I'm assuming it shouldn't affect the process though.

Does anyone know why is the package not being installed?

Comment: You have to ask package developer about package naming and installation. It seems that [only AUR](https://repology.org/projects/?search=eve-ng) has related package, they use name [`eve-ng-integration`](https://repology.org/project/eve-ng-integration/versions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to find a solution to the mismatched packages. One of the admins from the eve-ng forum gave me this:

```
wget -O - http://www.eve-ng.net/repo/eczema@ecze.com.gpg.key | sudo apt-key add -
apt-get update
apt-get -y install software-properties-common
sudo add-apt-repository "deb [arch=amd64]  http://www.eve-ng.net/repo xenial main"
apt-get update
apt-get install eve-ng-addons-netem
```